# Lowdb return undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, lowdb

I'm doing a Discord bot with command handling, but on a file, I can't get the content of my JSON file out with lowdb... I proceed exactly the same way with success in the other files, I don't understand... Here is my code:

```
const low = require('lowdb')
const FileSync = require('lowdb/adapters/FileSync')
const adapter = new FileSync('../db.json')
const db = low(adapter)
const adapter2 = new FileSync('../users.json')
const users = low(adapter2)
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const config = require('../config.json');
const api = config.api;

module.exports = {
    name: 'rent',
    description: 'Rent a number',
    usage: '<country>',
    guildOnly: true,

  async execute(message, args) {
    return console.log(db.get().value())

...
```

Here's my db.json:

```
{
  "numbers": [
    {
      "test": "1234"
    }
  ]
}
```

When I console.log db alone, it takes me out the object, but as soon as I try to console.log with lowdb like above it takes me out undefined ....

Comment: what is this supossed to return? `db.get().value()`

Comment: @TheFool The content of db.json

Comment: The lib is ment to query the file. If you simply want to get all content. Why don't you get the content with require? I think the package has no method to show you all the content of the file at once.

Comment: @TheFool I'm debugging step by step, aiming at a particular element in my file doesn't work either, so I just try to simply display the file first.

Comment: íd you try `db.get("numbers").find({test: '1234'}).value()` ?

Comment: Undefined too...

Comment: are you sure you are pointing to the right path of the file?

Comment: Yep sure, It is indeed in the parent folder of my current file

Comment: doesnt sound sure enough for me. Do something to confirm it. do a require() or read it with fs

Comment: https://repl.it/@bluebrown/CompatibleForsakenCharmap#index.js

Comment: @TheFool Output with require the db manually: { numbers: [ { test: '1234' } ] }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'm not sure why, but you have to remove a point on the road to lowdb files.

Code not working:

```
const low = require('lowdb')
const FileSync = require('lowdb/adapters/FileSync')
const adapter = new FileSync('../db.json')
const db = low(adapter)
const adapter2 = new FileSync('../users.json')
const users = low(adapter2)
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const config = require('../config.json');
const api = config.api;
```

Code after modification and functional:

```
const low = require('lowdb')
const FileSync = require('lowdb/adapters/FileSync')
const adapter = new FileSync('./db.json')
const db = low(adapter)
const adapter2 = new FileSync('./users.json')
const users = low(adapter2)
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const config = require('../config.json');
const api = config.api;
```

Comment: Not a point, but rather a whole directory. In unix environments, `..` refers to the parent directory, and `.` refers to the current directory

Comment: It looks like this command will import the dB from relative to the current directory of invoking the program while require looks relative to the file it was called from. Hence op may have to remove the one dot. This is also why we see oftentime the path module being required and used to resolve the path, in good code examples.